# Magento, hidden products /store view

Tags: magento, view, store, hidden

i have to insert in my store some new products, and i'd like to keep them hidden for users until i have uploaded them all and checked that is all ok.

I think that a **hidden store view** could be a good solution, but i don't know how to do it. Is possible ? any other solutions ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new store view by going to `System -> Manage Stores`. However, you will need to create a new `Store Name` to be able to assign a different top level category.

Alternatively, create your different `Store View` and add the new category to the existing structure, setting `Is Active` to `No` in `Manage Categories`. Then choose the new `Store View` from the dropdown in the top left on the category page, choose the new view, and change `Is Active` to `Yes` for that view only.

Does that give you enough of what you need?

Remember, different views and names can be given the same theme too.

Comment: yes i think i have to create a "test store" with a new directory structure, create the new products in it, check if all is ok from an alternate URL configured to display the test store, and for last put the new products in the "real store" directory tree. 
This last part has to be made for each single product right ? i have found no way to change the directory for many products at the same time.

Comment: Are these new products going to appear in new categories when moved to the real store, or be moved to the already existing categories?

Comment: Well you can automate some of these things using a csv file or something like Magmi. How many items are we talking about?

Comment: These new products will going to be moved in existing categories on the real store. Something like 100 Items
Thanks!